# Когда использовать при синхронизации Семафор?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, семафоры

Вопрос теоретический. При синхронизации потоков, можно использовать Lock, он же Монитор. Если это нужно в одном процессе. Если у нас отложенное выполнение задачи, то используем async/await. Мутекс можно использовать на уровне ОС. А зачем нам тогда класс Семафор, который регулирует потоки. И самое интересно я почти не видел ни разу чтобы использовали семафоры.

Comment: Монитор позволяет быть внутри секции только одному потоку. А что, если вам надо ограничиться не одним потоком внутри, а, например, тремя?

Comment: @tym32167 Вот ту и нужен семафор? или можно обойтись мутексом?

Comment: я нечасто этим пользуюсь, потому могу ошибаться, но мьютекс вроде только 1 поток пропускает.

Comment: Да   вы правы, получается если у нас более чем один поток, нужен семафор.

Comment: @tym32167 Если у нас внутри секции нужно организовать синхронизацию трех потоков. Тогда семафор будет  одному потоку разрешать доступ в секцию, двуми другим запрещать, потом когда первый поток закончит работу и выйдет из секции , семафор пустит туда второй поток.Третий и первый будет ожидать семафора. По логике получается, что так или иначе это тот же самый Lock но для нескольких потоков.

Comment: [Semaphore](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netframework-4.7.2) `Ограничивает число потоков, которые могут одновременно обращаться к ресурсу или пулу ресурсов.` Ключевое слово - `одновременно`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Семафор нужен для возможности ограничить количество одновременно выполняемых потоков.
Например:
У нас есть 100 сообщений но одновременно мы можем отправлять только 10.
В этом случае идеально подходит семафор.